# Can't edit article after Joomla 3.4.7 update

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, update

I've just updated from Joomla **3.4.6** to **3.4.7** and after doing so, I went to edit an article and received the following error message:

> **Error**
>
> You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page (#6).

Does anyone know why this is occurring?

Comment: #6 corresponds to the id of the article you are trying to access.

Comment: Logging out & back in worked for me too. Thanks; I was about to restore the whole system, ugh! Glad I checked here first -H

Comment: Comment by Alex-Logout and log in doesn't work in my case. Click on article leads to http://www.domain.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id
Php ini is set to 755

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The were session storage changes in the Joomla 3.4.7 update.

To fix the issue, you simply need to logout and log back in before you can make any article changes.

Reference: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Unable_To_Edit_Article_3.4.7